# Resolving interface property overriding conflicts

Tags: kotlin, interface

There is a nice example of resolving interface method conflicts at [kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/interfaces.html#resolving-overriding-conflicts)

But is there any solution for properties?

```
interface A {
    val foo: Foo
    fun process() {
        //do something with foo
    }
}
interface B: A {
    val bFoo: Foo
    override val foo: Foo get() = bFoo
}

interface C: A {
    val cFoo: Foo
    override val foo: Foo get() = cFoo
}

// Error:
// Class 'Bar' must override public open val foo: Foo
// because it inherits multiple interface methods of it
class Bar : B, C {
    override val bFoo = Foo()
    override val cFoo = Foo()

    override fun process() {
        super<B>.process()
        super<C>.process()
    }
}
```

Is it possible to resolve it to generic super getter? Something like this:

```
override val foo: Foo get() = super.foo
```

**Update**

I have update the original example by adding `process()` method for the complete picture. The challenge is that when we call `super<T>.process()` it should get the `foo` resolved by the getter in the proper interface.

Please, any solutions without passing `foo` as parameter to the method directly.

Comment: Well you can't use `super.foo`, because it is unclear which implementation you want to use. The implementation from `B`? Or the implementation from `C`?

Comment: You need to tell the compiler which _foo_  you want to override. If it shall be _B_, then it would be: _... = super<B>.foo_.

Comment: check the upated question please